# Why class template below compile in Visual Studio 2019 and does not with gcc 8.3?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, gcc

Why code below compile in Visual Studio 2019 and does not with gcc 8.3?

```cpp
#include<array>
template<typename T> class myClass {
public:
template<unsigned int N> myClass(const std::array<T, N>& elems) { /* do something */ }
};

int main() {
    std::array<int, 10> A;
    myClass<int> Tabular(A);
}
```

This is a snippet I extract from my student's project because it looks weird to me. I try this with gcc 8.3 and as I suspect the compiler complains that template argument deduction is failed. So I told my student that this does not work. But he argued that this do compile in VS without warning, I checked and he was right.

Because I'm very far from calling myself an expert,  I cannot explain to myself and my student whether/why/what is wrong.

Comment: Cheating is probably not the best choice of words.

Comment: you're right, i suppose that by ,,cheating'' I want to say ,,I dont understand''

Answer (score 5):

Both Gcc and MSVC are correct. The type of the 2nd template parameter of [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) is defined as `std::size_t`, and how [`std::size_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t) is defined depends on implementation.

> ```
> typedef /*implementation-defined*/ size_t;
> ```
>
> `std::size_t` is the unsigned integer type of the result of the sizeof operator `as well as the sizeof... operator and the alignof operator (since C++11)`.
>
> The bit width of `std::size_t` is not less than 16. (since C++11)

Then when `std::size_t` is defined as the same as `unsigned int` the code compiles fine, otherwise it would fail; type mismatch causes the non-type template argument deduction fails.

Change `unsigned int` to `std::size_t` then the code is guaranteed to be compiled well with any decent compilers. e.g.

```
template<typename T> class myClass {
public:
template<std::size_t N> myClass(const std::array<T, N>& elems) { /* do something */ }
};
```

And about why type mismatch causes the non-type template argument deduction fails.

(emphasis mine)

> If a non-type template parameter is used in the parameter list, and
>   the corresponding template argument is deduced, **the type of the
>   deduced template argument ( as specified in its enclosing template
>   parameter list, meaning references are preserved) must match the type
>   of the non-type template parameter exactly**, except that cv-qualifiers
>   are dropped, and except where the template argument is deduced from an
>   array bound—in that case any integral type is allowed, even bool
>   though it would always become true:
>
> ```
> template<int i> class A { };
> template<short s> void f(A<s>); // the type of the non-type template param is short
>
> void k1()
> {
>     A<1> a;  // the type of the non-type template param of a is int
>     f(a);    // P = A<(short)s>, A = A<(int)1>
>              // error: deduced non-type template argument does not have the same
>              // type as its corresponding template argument
>     f<1>(a); // OK: the template argument is not deduced, 
>              // this calls f<(short)1>(A<(short)1>)
> }
>
> template<int&> struct X;
> template<int& R> void k2(X<R>&);
> int n;
> void g(X<n> &x) {
>     k2(x); // P = X<R>, A = X<n>
>            // parameter type is int&
>            // argument type is int& in struct X's template declaration
>            // OK (with CWG 2091): deduces R to refer to n
> }
> ```

Comment: size_t in MSVC is a 64-bit type in 64-bit mode, but the above snippet can still compile properly https://godbolt.org/z/_juS-o but yes, gcc and Clang do compile it if I use `-m32` option

Comment: @phuclv It might be MSVC's issue; I added the reference about why type mismatch causes the non-type template argument deduction fails.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you have template errors like this, the best thing you can do is try different compilers, and see what errors they will give you. [CompilerExplorer](https://godbolt.org/z/CQaJSy) is a really good site for this

GCC says:

```
<source>:4:26: note: candidate: 'template<unsigned int N> myClass<T>::myClass(const std::array<T, N>&) [with unsigned int N = N; T = int]'

    4 | template<unsigned int N> myClass(const std::array<T, N>& elems) { /* do something */ }

      |                          ^~~~~~~

<source>:4:26: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:

<source>:9:27: note:   mismatched types 'unsigned int' and 'long unsigned int'

    9 |     myClass<int> Tabular(A);

      |
```

Clang says:

```
<source>:4:26: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure: deduced non-type template argument does not have the same type as the corresponding template parameter ('unsigned long' vs 'unsigned int')

template<unsigned int N> myClass(const std::array<T, N>& elems) { /* do something */ }
```

As you can see, both GCC and Clang failed to subsitute `long unsigned int` (`std::size_t`) with a `unsigned int`.

Comment: Don't normally do"+1" type comments,  but really appreciate the link to ComplierExplorer!